# Change the value of a field in multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to clean up data in two tables.
These are my tables:

Table 1

```
id     |   name  |   visible
48871  |   John  |      0
9711015|   Luke  |      1
547574 |   Mike  |      0
```

Table 2

```
id     |   parent_id  |   visible
1      |   48871      |      0
2      |   9711015    |      1
3      |   547574     |      0
```

I would like to update the ids of id (first table) and parent_id (second table) increasingly. So I would like to transform the two tables like this:

Table 1

```
id     |   name  |   visible
1      |   John  |      0
2      |   Luke  |      1
3      |   Mike  |      0
```

Table 2

```
id     |   parent_id  |   visible
1      |       1      |      0
2      |       2      |      1
3      |       3      |      0
```

It's possible? What should i use?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff done, mysql

Comment: What version of MySQL? Also are there any ordering rules to define the running id number? Order by (table 1) name or id, ascending or descending?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL lets up update multiple tables at the same time.  So, you can do:

```
update table1 t1 join
       (select t1.*,
               row_number() over (order by t1.id) as new_id
        from table1 t1
       ) tt1
       on t1.id = tt1.id left join
       table2 t2
       on t2.parent_id = t1.id
    set t1.id = tt1.new_id,
        t2.parent_id = tt1.new_id;
```